# Rails & Heroku: We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting the infamous "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error. Googling it it points to Omniauth problem - but I havent changed much (if any) of the omniauth stuff, and had it working last time I deployed it to heroku.

I have it deployed on a cedar stack btw.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Heroku logs:

```
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.0.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call!'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.0.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:148:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2587592208680042819__call__3254396045512618553__callbacks'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
```

I also noticed the following:

```
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:29:in `determine_template'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `_render_template'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3927484994384413162__process_action__1065190525946390676__callbacks'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2012-04-28T18:26:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
```

Comment: might just want to do a double check, and make sure your main application files are on the repository correctly. If you're running just fine locally, and the remote looks good, you might want to contact heroku support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems really out of the blue, but what fixed my problem was having the haml gem within the assets group. I took it out from that particular group, and it fixed my problem. Not sure why.

Comment: Saved my day. I had same problem and bringing haml out of assets group solved the issue. Any idea why?