# Heroku deployment issues - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've searched all over stack overflow and the web and tried various fixes but I'm still unable to get my rails app running on heroku. I am consistently receiving the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error from heroku.

The app runs fine in my local environment.

I've done the following:

- Run "heroku rake run db:migrate"
- Verified that my assets are being compiled correctly: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar
- Implemented Thin server and created a procfile as referenced here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

I would really appreciate your help in analyzing my heroku logs file (below) to figure out what's causing this error.

My app is running on Rails 3.2.7, Ruby 1.9.3 and uses postgres as the db

```
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 heroku[router]: GET glacial-headland-3472.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=267ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3080287486243242199__process_action__1142231311061748289__callbacks'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7
/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1576820621715372704__call__3414544984041752206__callbacks'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-28T17:55:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 68ms
2012-08-28T17:55:59+00:00 heroku[router]: GET glacial-headland-3472.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: did you try emailing the heroku team?  Their tutorials are generally correct.

Comment: I continued my search for a solution on stack overflow and found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366394/rails-heroku-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong?rq=1

I removed my "haml-rails" gem from the assets group (and made it accessible to all groups) and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued my search for a solution on stack overflow and found my answer here;
[Rails & Heroku: We're sorry, but something went wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366394/rails-heroku-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong?rq=1)

I removed my "haml-rails" gem from the assets group (and platop of the file) and this fixed my issue.